# How to deal with advisor writing a thesis chapter for you?

Tags: thesis, advisor, ethics, etiquette, undergraduate

How would you respond if an advisor writes a chapter of your thesis for you and asks you to rewrite what they wrote? Something seems wrong but I can't pinpoint it. It seems like a grey area. What are the potential plagiarism implications if I do this? And how can a student rewrite it any better than what someone with so much experience has written?

What would be an ethical and courteous way to respond? If there are any other sources or places you think I might be able to find more information or help from about this, I would like to hear that too.

Comment: More detail is needed. Why does the advisor want to do this? Is it just a matter of being a more natural writer in the language of choice? Whose work is it (the underlying research)? Who gets credit?

Comment: @Buffy I'm not sure why the advisor wants to do this. I don't think it's being a more natural writer, but they are much more knowledgeable about the topic than me. I don't know how it works in research and so am unsure about whose work it is: I did the work but the idea is from the advisor and they have been assisting. Does that still make the underlying research my own work? I am the one being assessed for my own thesis so I would be receiving the credit.

Comment: What level thesis is this? Undergrad? Masters? Doctoral?

Comment: @Buffy Undergrad

Comment: And, is it the crux chapter or just "fill in" information to make it more complete? I don't know if I have an answer. I can imagine a benign scenario or one that is not so good, but I'm hoping it is more toward the former than the latter.

Comment: In an ideal world, you would ask the advisor why, and ask them what are the consequences. Maybe you can do that.

Comment: Maybe the idea is that it's a sample of how to write - it might be a didactic trick to teach a student who does not know how to write, how to do so. After all, they ask the student to rewrite it, and the other chapters need to be written, too. I am hesitant to judge before I have the whole picture.

Comment: @Buffy, It's the crux of the chapter. I think there is room for me to add some "fill in" information.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs That may be a reason. I am not familiar with writing thesis chapters yet and what they wrote seems like a good sample.

Comment: @Buffy I asked. They said it's for learning purposes that they did that and that it's ok for me to do so. But it just doesn't sit right. I'm not sure if I can ask them about the consequences.

Comment: What discipline is this? I imagine this could be a very different case depending on the discipline. If it's a discipline where writing mostly involves reporting results of research, and you've done the research and gotten the results, then I see this as being a possibly valid pedagogical approach. But in other disciplines, where writing is more integral to the research itself (humanities disciplines, for example), I'd be more inclined to think this was either really poor pedagogy or even unethical.

Comment: Forget issue as plagiarism. It can mean various things. Some acceptable some not. Some related to ethics but just marginally. I've personally upvoted Spark answer. I could extend that answer, but all boils down to your relationship with the supervisor. Ideally, there should be a discussion. I can also imagine desperate cases in which at the end the supervisor has no choice but to write. I personally think that a undergraduate thesis is anyway interpreted as a product of the student and the supervisor.

Comment: @transitionsynthesis It's a discipline that mostly involves reporting results of research, which I guess makes it more of a pedagogical approach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few possible reasons:

1. The advisor is not very experienced with advising students and is not clear on what they are supposed to do.
2. The advisor intends to publish the thesis with the student and is therefore interested in ensuring that the specific chapter is properly written.
3. The advisor is not confident in the student’s ability to correctly formulate certain ideas.

What can the student do? Ask the advisor politely to lead the writing of the thesis, write a first draft that they can later review. If the advisor insists, I suggest letting it go. It’s one chapter and is not a very big deal if it is indeed an undergraduate thesis. Helping students write is not unethical unless the student is really not leading the project. However in that case I fail to see why the advisor would take the thesis writing as their own project...

Comment: @[Spark] For an undergraduate thesis, what does it look like if the student is leading the project? I'm not sure, maybe I am not leading it? I don't know how much advice an advisor should give to new students because doesn't the student first have to learn the ropes first? My advisor gave me many things to do and there wasn't much chance for me to go my own way yet.

Comment: One rule of thumb would be - can you confidently explain every idea that you present in the thesis to a professional audience? I don’t think you need to necessarily come up with all of the ideas but you should absolutely know in detail what’s happening

Comment: @[Spark] Thank you for the rule of thumb. Yes, in that case, I think I can explain it to a professional audience.

Answer (score 3):

For PhD students: If the advisor conducts the research, the student must not submit that research as part of their thesis.  If the advisor did the research, it does not matter who did the writing: for the student to include it in their PhD thesis would be plagiarism if unattributed or, if attributed, fail to meet the standard required for a PhD.  A PhD student in this situation should respond by expressing a desire to demonstrate their ability to work independently.

If it is not a PhD thesis but at a lower level, it might be okay for a student to write about someone else's research if proper attribution is given.

If the student did the research but the advisor wrote it up, this is not ideal.  However, in some disciplines it may be considered acceptable for an advisor to give extensive writing assistance to PhD students.

> And how can a student rewrite it any better than what someone with so much experience has written?

Probably the goal is to rewrite it to be in your own words, not to rewrite it to be better.

I would suggest outlining the writing, and then changing the structure of the outline.  Check the new structure with your advisor to make sure it is acceptable.  Then rewrite according to the outline.

Comment: I guess I missed the "undergraduate" tag.

Comment: @[Anonymous Physicist] How might proper attribution be given in this case? Do I write a sentence at the beginning of the chapter? Thank you, that's a good way to think about the goal of rewriting, like writing my own notes from reading.

Comment: Ask your advisor.

Comment: @[Anonymous Physicist] Ok, thank you I guess they might know better.